# Javascript revealing module pattern - references

Tags: javascript, reference, design-patterns

Here's what I've run into...
I design my object:

```
var Tab = function () {
    var _data = [], _owners = [], _supportWorkers = [], _watchers = [];
        var _dataLength = function () { return _data.length; };
    return {
        Data: _data,
        Owners: _owners,
        SupportWorkers: _supportWorkers,
        Watchers: _watchers,
            Length: _dataLength
    };
};

var newObject = new Tab();
newObject.Data = [{"my":"data"}];
alert(newObject.Length()); // Length == 0
alert(newObject.Data.length);​ // Length == 1
```

This obviously changes the reference, but does not change the reference INSIDE the object. Is creating a Getter/Setter function the only way to avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _dataLength = function () { return this.Data.length; };
```

Will work from the outside, since `this` will refer to the instance. It will not work from within the module itself.

---

Here's how I would do it - the revealing module pattern is pointless if all your data is revealed:

```
var Tab = function () { 
    this.data = [];
    this.owners = [];
    this.supportWorkers = [];
    this.watchers = [];
}
Tab.prototype.dataLength = function () { return this.data.length; };
```

Comment: So, for a String or a Number it would be pointless to have default data that is modifiable from the outside. I would always have to refer to the variable _myString in my functions as this["MyString"], rather than _myString?

I wish modifying .Data wouldn't change the reference OF .Data, but the referenced object.

So, if I need default values, I should create Getter/Setter control over the variables.

Comment: I find its much easier to use `this` for all public members, and skip the return statement.

Comment: Yeah, it would be easier. I hate always referring to this.* It really-really gets old fast.